# What is the better approach for Storing financial stock/funds data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, time-series

I need to store financial data of funds, typically end of day values of the stocks underneath. And every day the fund may change in terms of the stocks it has (holdings). My system may have up to a 1000 funds at maximum. Each fund, may have from 1000 - 100,000 stocks (positions) under them. Some stat values of these stocks are going to be stored on a daily basis.

So every day, the fund will go through a change in number of stocks it has (may have newly added stock / have some of them removed), and the stat values of the stocks will undergo a change. This daily holding data will be appended to the existing data of the fund.

That is, we have a hierarchy like below: 
    fund1 --> date1 --> holding: {stock1: {stat values array}, stock2: {stat values array}},
    fund1 --> date2 --> holding: {stock1: {stat values array}, stock2: {stat values array}, stock3: {stat values array}}

What is the better way to store the data for faster retrieval? Some statistical calculations are going to be done over the data after retrieval.

1. Should I create a single collection to maintain all the funds data in it? Schema will be like (fundId, date, holding), and holding will have an embedded document of stock holding data for that day. That is, for an year, 1000 funds * 260 working days * (1000 - 100000) stocks data for each day for each fund, will go into this single collection. Will this perform good in the long run say after 3 years with all the data?
2. Should I create a collection for each fund? That will be, say, 1000 collections. This way, I'll just have (date, holding) per collection, but I'll need to query across collections if I need to retrieve data of many funds at once for joining. This can go up to 100 funds - 150 funds at times. Does this hit performance?

Thank you for any help.